# remove shifting of inputs on success validation in HTML

Tags: html, css, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to be all in one line (has-error and has-success)
Now, situation is like this: [image: bad alignment]

I am using BootstrapValidator and Bootstrap.
Here is my HTML:

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>BootStrap Datepicker Re-validation</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bootstrapvalidator/bootstrapValidator.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- This is my custom css, it's not relevant for this post
<link href="css/glyphicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/glass.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/test0.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->

</head>

<body>
<form class="form-inline" role="form" id="form-div" method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-group required">
        <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
            <input type="text" id="checkIn" type="text" class="form-control datepickstart" placeholder="Check-in" name="dobfrom" />
            <label for="calendar" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" rel="tooltip" title="Choose check-in date"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
            <input type="text" id="checkOut" type="text" class="form-control datepickstart" placeholder="Check-out" name="dobto" />
            <label for="calendar" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" rel="tooltip" title="Choose check-in date"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
            <select class="form-control" name="aptList">
                 <option value="">Select Apartment</option>
                 <option value="apt1">Apartment 1</option>
                 <option value="apt2">Apartment 2</option>
            </select>
            <label for="apt" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" rel="tooltip" title="Choose apartment"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
            <input type="text" data-validation="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" name="email">
            <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" rel="tooltip" title="Enter mail address"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
            <input type="text" class="form-control person" data-validation="required" id="inputGuests" placeholder="Adults" name="adult">
            <label for="adults" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" rel="tooltip" title="Choose number of adults"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
            <input type="text" class="form-control person" data-validation="required" id="inputChildren" placeholder="Children" name="child">
            <label for="adults" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" rel="tooltip" title="Choose number of adults"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrapvalidator/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/autonumeric@4.0.1"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#checkIn').datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
            })
            .on('changeDate', function(e) {
                // Revalidate the date field
                $('#form-div').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'dobfrom');
            });
        $('#checkOut').datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
            })
            .on('changeDate', function(e) {
                // Revalidate the date field
                $('#form-div').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'dobto');
            });
        $('#form-div').bootstrapValidator({
            message: 'This value is not valid',
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: '',
                invalid: '',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                aptList: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The Apartment is required and can\'t be empty'
                        }
                    }
                },
                child: {
                    message: 'The username is not valid',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The username is required and can\'t be empty'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp: /^[0-9]+$/,
                            message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                        }
                    }
                },
                adult: {
                    message: 'The username is not valid',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The username is required and can\'t be empty'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp: /^[0-9]+$/,
                            message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                        }
                    }
                },
                email: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The email address is required and can\'t be empty'
                        },
                        emailAddress: {
                            message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
                        }
                    }
                },
                dobfrom: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'DOB is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        date: {
                            message: 'The value is not a valid date',
                            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
                        }
                    }
                }, //dobfrom           
                dobto: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'DOB is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        date: {
                            message: 'The value is not a valid date',
                            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
                        }
                    }
                } //dobto                 
            } //fields
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Basically, I want to be all aligned, just on has-success to disappear error div below?
I was looking in bootstrap.min.css but it seems it is all OK.
Also in a bootstrapValidator.css I have some classes that not influence on this matter.

Comment: Not really sure what your question is, but if you just want the <input> elements to align, you could either go the flexbox route, or just apply position: absolute to your error message containers?

Comment: just try this: `.form-inline .form-group {vertical-align: top;}`

Answer (score 0):

i think you should separate to two divs the form, in the first div all the form divs , Apart from the last div

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the second form you need to put this-

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

this way the message will appear in different div

search divA, divB:

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>BootStrap Datepicker Re-validation</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bootstrapvalidator/bootstrapValidator.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- This is my custom css, it's not relevant for this post
<link href="css/glyphicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/glass.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/test0.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->

</head>

<body>
<form class="form-inline" role="form" id="form-div" method="post" action="">
<div class="divA">
    <div class="form-group required">
        <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
            <input type="text" id="checkIn" type="text" class="form-control datepickstart" placeholder="Check-in" name="dobfrom" />
            <label for="calendar" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" rel="tooltip" title="Choose check-in date"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
            <input type="text" id="checkOut" type="text" class="form-control datepickstart" placeholder="Check-out" name="dobto" />
            <label for="calendar" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" rel="tooltip" title="Choose check-in date"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
            <select class="form-control" name="aptList">
                 <option value="">Select Apartment</option>
                 <option value="apt1">Apartment 1</option>
                 <option value="apt2">Apartment 2</option>
            </select>
            <label for="apt" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" rel="tooltip" title="Choose apartment"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
            <input type="text" data-validation="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" name="email">
            <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" rel="tooltip" title="Enter mail address"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
            <input type="text" class="form-control person" data-validation="required" id="inputGuests" placeholder="Adults" name="adult">
            <label for="adults" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" rel="tooltip" title="Choose number of adults"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <div class="icon-addon addon-md">
            <input type="text" class="form-control person" data-validation="required" id="inputChildren" placeholder="Children" name="child">
            <label for="adults" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" rel="tooltip" title="Choose number of adults"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="divB">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>

<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrapvalidator/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/autonumeric@4.0.1"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#checkIn').datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
            })
            .on('changeDate', function(e) {
                // Revalidate the date field
                $('#form-div').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'dobfrom');
            });
        $('#checkOut').datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
            })
            .on('changeDate', function(e) {
                // Revalidate the date field
                $('#form-div').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'dobto');
            });
        $('#form-div').bootstrapValidator({
            message: 'This value is not valid',
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: '',
                invalid: '',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                aptList: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The Apartment is required and can\'t be empty'
                        }
                    }
                },
                child: {
                    message: 'The username is not valid',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The username is required and can\'t be empty'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp: /^[0-9]+$/,
                            message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                        }
                    }
                },
                adult: {
                    message: 'The username is not valid',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The username is required and can\'t be empty'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp: /^[0-9]+$/,
                            message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                        }
                    }
                },
                email: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The email address is required and can\'t be empty'
                        },
                        emailAddress: {
                            message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
                        }
                    }
                },
                dobfrom: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'DOB is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        date: {
                            message: 'The value is not a valid date',
                            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
                        }
                    }
                }, //dobfrom           
                dobto: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'DOB is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        date: {
                            message: 'The value is not a valid date',
                            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
                        }
                    }
                } //dobto                 
            } //fields
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: can you describe a little more. That you wrote it seems to me to add twice submit buttons?